# EZMicrophone EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I'm working on a project that makes the recording sound.
To record the audio, I used the library EZAudio which allows me to see the wave.
The object in a ViewController in turn inserted within a UINavigationController, but unfortunately when I come back I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I do not know how to solve ...
I think the problem is the UINavigationController ...

Here is the code Interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EZAudio.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>



    @interface AudioViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate, EZMicrophoneDelegate>
    {

    }
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet EZAudioPlotGL *plotGL;
    @property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL isRecording;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) EZMicrophone *microphone;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) EZRecorder *recorder;
    @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonRecorder;

    -(IBAction)recordingAudio:(id)sender;

    @end
```

Here is the code Implementation:

```
@implementation AudioViewController
@synthesize plotGL, isRecording, microphone, recorder, buttonRecorder;

-(void)toggleRecording:(id)sender{

}


-(void)recordingAudio:(id)sender{
    if(self.isRecording == YES){
        self.isRecording = NO;
    }
    else{
        self.isRecording = YES;
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    //Inizializzo il microfono
    self.microphone = [EZMicrophone microphoneWithDelegate:self];

    self.plotGL.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.plotGL.color           = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.plotGL.plotType        = EZPlotTypeBuffer;

    self.plotGL.shouldFill      = NO;
    self.plotGL.shouldMirror    = NO;

    [self.microphone startFetchingAudio];




    NSArray *syms = [NSThread  callStackSymbols];
    if ([syms count] > 1) {
        NSLog(@"<%@ %p> %@ - caller: %@ ", [self class], self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),[syms objectAtIndex:1]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"<%@ %p> %@", [self class], self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone
 hasAudioReceived:(float **)buffer
   withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize
    withNumberOfChannels:(UInt32)numberOfChannels {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

        [self.plotGL updateBuffer:buffer[0] withBufferSize:bufferSize];
    });
}

-(void)microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone hasAudioStreamBasicDescription:(AudioStreamBasicDescription)audioStreamBasicDescription {

    [EZAudio printASBD:audioStreamBasicDescription];
    self.recorder = [EZRecorder recorderWithDestinationURL:[self getAudioFile]
                                           andSourceFormat:audioStreamBasicDescription];
}

-(void)microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone
    hasBufferList:(AudioBufferList *)bufferList
   withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize
withNumberOfChannels:(UInt32)numberOfChannels {

    if( self.isRecording ){
        [self.recorder appendDataFromBufferList:bufferList
                                 withBufferSize:bufferSize];
    }

}

#pragma mark - AVAudioPlayerDelegate
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [self.microphone stopFetchingAudio];
}



#pragma mark - Utility
-(NSArray*)applicationDocuments {
    return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
}

-(NSString*)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSLog(@"basePath %@",basePath);
    return basePath;
}

-(NSURL*)getAudioFile {

    NSString *fileName = @"audio.wav";
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[self applicationDocumentsDirectory],fileName]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry...i use Google Translate :-)

Comment: Can you show the crash log and the code for adding the `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController`?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand

Comment: No problem, let me say it in a different way: Can you show "problem message" from Xcode for EXC_BAD_ACCESS and `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Hello, 
below the picture of the error I get ... 
If you want I can send you the project but do not know how .... 
If you need anything else let me know. 

[link](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/811/3lco.png)

Comment: Check and see if this works: change: ....(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet EZAudioPlotGL *plotGL; ---> ...(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet EZAudioPlotGL *plotGL;

Comment: Hello, 
other information a ... 
I have installed the application within the device and I have a different error. 
The EXC_BAD_ACCESS now I get to this line of code 
EZMicrophone microphone * = (__bridge EZMicrophone *) inRefCon; 


The following error 
[Error on device](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/543/7kx5.png)

Comment: Great....but now i have another error   EZMicrophone microphone * = (__bridge EZMicrophone *) inRefCon; [ERROR on DEVICE](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/543/7kx5.png)

Comment: Hi, I would need more information for the last problem.

Comment: Hello, 
I solved the problem. 
I just had to implement the dealloc method. 
I solved it this way: 

[self.microphone stopFetchingAudio]; 
microphone.microphoneDelegate = nil; 
microphone = nil;

Comment: Great, happy for you. You could post that an answer including my first solution, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please insert:

```
(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet EZAudioPlotGL *plotGL; ---> ...(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet EZAudioPlotGL *plotGL;
```